# converting rows to columns using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

I'm trying to convert rows into columns using the following sample:

| LVL | COL_VALUE | TABLE_SRC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | INT: ADDRESS_LINE_2:NULL | INT |
| 16 | BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_2:X | BASE |
| 17 | INT: ADDRESS_LINE_3:NULL | INT |
| 17 | BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_3:X | BASE |

The output should be:

| INT | BASE |
| --- | --- |
| INT: ADDRESS_LINE_2:NULL | BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_2:X |
| INT: ADDRESS_LINE_3:NULL | BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_3:X |

The COL_VALUE with the same LVL should be in 1 row

I tried using PIVOT but it returns only 1 row because of the aggregate function

```
SELECT *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
                 BATCH_ID
                ,CONTACT_ID
                ,COL_VALUE
                ,TABLE_SRC
        FROM
            MISMATCH
        )
PIVOT
    (
        max(COL_VALUE) FOR TABLE_SRC IN ('1BASE' BASE, '1INT' INT)
    )
```

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected output as text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `LVL` in the inner sub-query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT  BATCH_ID
         ,CONTACT_ID
         ,COL_VALUE
         ,TABLE_SRC
         ,LVL
  FROM   MISMATCH
) PIVOT (
  max(COL_VALUE)
  FOR TABLE_SRC IN ('1BASE' BASE, '1INT' INT)
)
```

If you don't want it in the output then change from `SELECT *` to a list of columns.

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mismatch (batch_id, contact_id, LVL, COL_VALUE, TABLE_SRC) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 16, 'INT: ADDRESS_LINE_2:NULL', '1INT'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 16, 'BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_2:X',   '1BASE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 17, 'INT: ADDRESS_LINE_3:NULL', '1INT'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 17, 'BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_3:X',   '1BASE' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | BATCH_ID | CONTACT_ID | LVL | BASE | INT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 16 | BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_2:X | INT: ADDRESS_LINE_2:NULL |
> | 1 | 1 | 17 | BASE: ADDRESS_LINE_3:X | INT: ADDRESS_LINE_3:NULL |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d0a05e75f9dfeab4f6976c4c3459874)*